# Tkinter : problem if i need to print path from asksaveasfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**I have this code:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog

class Home():
    def init(self):

     self.bu = Button(self, text="Save")
     self.bu.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, stick="w", pady=30)
     self.bu.config(command=self.save_result)

    def save(self):
        """Save result"""
        f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialfile="save.txt", defaultextension=".txt")

        print(f)
```

**The Result is:**

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/save.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I need to print just path `"C:/Users/JOHN/Desktop/save.txt"`.

Answer (score 2):

I find the answer :

```
from tkinter import filedialog

class Home():
    def init(self):

     self.bu = Button(self, text="Save")
     self.bu.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, stick="w", pady=30)
     self.bu.config(command=self.save_result)

    def save(self):
        """Save result"""
        f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialfile="save.txt", defaultextension=".txt")

        print(f.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for `filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`. This returns the name, and not an open handle to a file object. You then have to open the file yourself (this is a better idea anyways, as you generally do not want handles floating around).

```py
def save(self):
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        file.write(self.data)
```

Comment: Thanks , I fix it just need path folder

Comment: You just want the folder? Not the file name?

Comment: No, I need the file full path, I fix it above thanks